# Javascript Decrypt C# AES Encryption

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt a C# encrypt string using javascript,

This is an example of the encryption on my server side

```
 public class AesCrypt
{
    public static string IV = @"!QAZ2WSX#EDC4RFV";
    public static string Key = @"5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<";
    public static string Encrypt(string dectypted)
    {

        byte[] textbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dectypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider encdec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        encdec.BlockSize = 128;
        encdec.KeySize = 256;
        encdec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
        encdec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
        encdec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        encdec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        ICryptoTransform icrypt = encdec.CreateEncryptor(encdec.Key, encdec.IV);

        byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
        icrypt.Dispose();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(enc);
    }
}
```

The encryption of `"Hello World"` is `"1i4zI5rB3Df2CYFalsiTwg=="`

Now I'm trying to decrypt it using js on my client and get `Hello World` and this is where I fail,

I'm using `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>` in order to decrypt and I watch some of examples over the web (including stackoverflow).

Accoring to some examples over the web this is what I came out of, but it's not returning "Hello World" back.

```
data = "1i4zI5rB3Df2CYFalsiTwg==";
key = "5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<";
iv = "!QAZ2WSX#EDC4RFV";

CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(atob(data), key, {
    iv: atob(iv),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
```

I'm using the same mode and padding, but I'm probably missing something.
I'm not that familiar with CryptoJS and I hope someone can help me understand where I went wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you have is insecure.  It uses a fixed IV.  You should fix that first.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark This is for studing purpose, but can you please explain more?

Comment: If you're studying encryption, you should probably study how to do it correctly ;) using a fixed IV introduces security flaws.  Under the right circumstances, you can retrieve the plaintext from the ciphertext.  You should randomly generate the IV for every encryption and just attach it to the ciphertext.  It doesn't have to be secret, just random.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark thanks for the headup, can you please direct me to any guide or tutrial if you have any?

Comment: Something like `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});` should do.

Comment: @Evk the result I got includes words array with those numbers  
`words:Array(4)
0:1214606444
1:1864390511
2:1919706117
3:84215045`
I got similar result with my code as well,

Comment: @Evk it returns a string with those numbers `1214606444,1864390511,1919706117,84215045`

Comment: Yes, you need to call `result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)`

Comment: @Evk tried that and it returns an empty string  

`result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);`

all returns an empty string

Comment: Here is a fiddle which outputs what you need, with the exact code shown in above comments: https://jsfiddle.net/o7945gv5/1/

Comment: Thanks @Evk  
I will compare with mine and see where i went wrong

Answer (score 0):

From the [old CryptoJS pages](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/), the Cipher input part:

> For the key, **when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase** and used to derive an actual key and IV. Or you can pass a WordArray that represents the actual key. If you pass the actual key, you must also pass the actual IV.

Although you are passing an IV, you do currently put in a string rather than a binary key as word array. I suppose this is the problem as I don't see any other obvious *programming* mistakes.